# How to identify column where value drops below 0

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to figure out a formula to identify in which column the value falls below 0.

I have thousands of rows and dozens of columns, so doing this manually isn't an option

So if my columns and values are as follows:

```
    A   B   C   D
1   Jul Aug Sep Oct
2   25  10  5   -2
3   10  2   -6  -10
```

So for row 2 I would like to return the result "Oct" (or 4 as the 4th column)as this is the month the value drops below 0. For row 3 I would like to return the value "Sep" (or 3 as the 3rd column).

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you returning the result to?

Comment: In this simple example it could be to column E, rows 2 and 3 (with row 1 being the column heading)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a little simpler to use INDEX/MATCH e.g. this array formula in AV10

`=INDEX(AW$1:BM$1,MATCH(TRUE,AW10:BM10<0,0))`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

or if you prefer to avoid CSE then add another INDEX function like this and formula can be entered "normally"

`=INDEX(AW$1:BM$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(AW10:BM10<0,0),0))`

If there are no numbers < 0 then that will return #N/A error......or you can use IFERROR function to replace with some text, e.g.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(AW$1:BM$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(AW10:BM10<0,0),0)),"No negative numbers")`

Comment: Many thanks! that worked perfectly! you're a star!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an array formula. In row 2, select your cell where you want the formula, paste the following into the formula bar, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$D$1,MIN(IF(A2:D2<0,COLUMN(A2:D2))))
```

For reference, `A1:D1` is the range of column headers (months), and `A2:D2` are the values in the row. What this formula does is look for values less than 0 and then takes the one with smallest column number. It then returns the month header in that column number.

This formula can be filled down to all rows.

**EDIT:**
If your data does not start at column A, you will have to make a small adjustment to the formula to get it to work. Everything stays the same in the formula except the first argument of the `INDEX` function must be extended to column A. For example, if your data starts in column C, then you would use the following formula instead (entered as an array formula).

```
=INDEX($A$1:$F$1,MIN(IF(C2:F2<0,COLUMN(C2:F2))))
```

The reason for this is that the `INDEX` function's second argument indicates the position in the array, not necessarily the column number. This distinction is obliterated if you just extend the array all the way to column A though (i.e., position in array will equal column number).

Comment: Hi thanks for that... not quite working however. I've entered the formula =INDEX(AW$1:BM$1,MIN(IF(AW10:BM10<0,COLUMN(AW10:BM10)))) in cell AV10 as my test data is in the range AW10:BM10..... the titles are in row 1. The first column where the data falls below 0 is BM. When I enter the formula above it returns the error #VALUE!.... any ideas? Thanks again

Comment: Sorry I hit return before I'd finished my response :-/

Comment: Ah ok, the issue is that your data does not start at column A as your example showed. Try this instead: `=INDEX(A$1:BM$1,MIN(IF(AW10:BM10<0,COLUMN(AW10:BM10))))`.